# How to list the post titles of all the post from my blogspot blog?

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I want to display ALL the blog post I've written to my visitors. Blogspot has 'Archive' widget but it displays only the post posted in a particular month/year. I want to display all the posts.
Is there any solution to that without using javascript??

(i don't want to use javascript 'cuz some users might have their script disabled)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a script i guess look at this > http://www.chethstudios.net/p/archives_09.html he is using a seamless script on blogger platform.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but since I did face the same issue by myself today, I wanted to share one possible solution : just add a `HTML/JavaScript` gadget with the following code :

```
<div id="all_post_root">Loading ...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Sort the items with respect to their title
var entriesComparator = function(a, b) {
  return a.link[2].title > b.link[2].title;
}

var displayFeed = function(response) {
  var entries = response.feed.entry;
  entries.sort(entriesComparator);

  var listUl = document.createElement("ul");
  for (var i in entries) {
     var elt = entries[i].link[2];

     var a = document.createElement("a");
     a.href = elt.href;
     a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(elt.title));

     var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.appendChild(a);

     listUl.appendChild(li);
  }

  var allPostRoot = document.getElementById('all_post_root');
  allPostRoot.innerHTML = "";
  allPostRoot.appendChild(listUl);
};
</script>

<script src="/feeds/posts/default?alt=json&callback=displayFeed">
</script>
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: can you post a screenshot please of the result of this?

Comment: This doesn't work at all. I assume Blogger has changed a fair bit since this was posted.